# How to disable port 80 on IIS while keeping port 443 open?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I have a potentially simple question, but after searching the forums could not find a clear answer:

Per security finding, we need to disable port 80 on IIS (on Windows 2008 Enterprise, IIS 7.5) to make sure a potential intruder cannot connect to port 80 and is forced to use port 443 for SSL.

The web application we have (vendor app written in .NET) does not use port 80 so it's safe to disable it.

Do I just remove port 80 from the bindings setting? How can I easily disable port 80 on IIS?

Comment: Removing the binding might be the best solution. Also, it might be better to force the website to use 443. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/29/iis7-how-to-force-a-website-to-use-ssl/ .

Comment: Yes, you just remove port 80 with Edit Bindings.  But you'll need a cert to add https and 443.

Comment: The same question was asked on the [iis forum](https://forums.iis.net/t/1155233.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

In IIS, click your web site, then click Bindings and Remove the Port 80 entry, you must have the other entry for 443 before you can remove the one for Port 80.